# Express eTag always changing

Tags: node.js, express, etag

I have a rest like API through Node Express.
The ETag is default, not explicitly turned on or off. However whenever I test hitting the server, it always gives me a new ETag, even if the returned JSON/HTML is exactly the same. I also checked the returned header and they look the same. I tested this with two types of content, an API and a static HTML content like a privacy page.

Any idea how to check what's making it different each time?

Answer (score 4):

Express' default behavior is to provide a "strong"-ly validated etag which will only be the same as a previous response if the current response is *precisely* the same, byte-for-byte.

You could try setting express' etag to weally validate the response, which indicates to the browser that the current response is semantically equivalent as a previous one with the same value, that is, while they might not be byte-for-byte the same, they encapulate or represent the same meaning. To do this, use `app.set('etag','weak')`

Finally, if this doesn't work for you, you can create your own etag validation function using `app.get('etag',function(body,encoding){...})` where you return a hash generated from your content; this allows you to control what express (and thus, the browser) considers *being different* means in the context of your response.

More than you ever wanted to know about etags can be found at [Wikipedi:HTTP_ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)

Comment: Thanks. What is 'precisely' the same, if the json response is exactly the same, what else does it take into account? certain headers?

Comment: ETags are hashes of the body of a response. Try returning a static file to see if the ETag changes. If it does, something is broken in your configuration. If it doesn't, then the responses you get from your API call are not the same. Try saving two differing responses to files and run `diff` on them to determine how they, er, differ. ;)

Comment: Also, under the covers, express uses the "etag" package from npm ([etag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/etag)). You might find your answer there as well.